# UML ternary and reflexive association together

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, uml, ternary

Using UML, I want to create the relation between : table user ( the user could be Buyer or Seller) and table job.

The buyer could leave feedbacks to seller and  vice versa.

So, my approach is the following:

- Reflexive relation between table user (buyer or seller)
- Ternary relation between table user and table job
- Association relating to ternary relation

Please find enclosed the following attemp: 
[image]

I need yours helps to know if is this correct or not ?

IF YOU HAVE ONOTHER CONCEPTION TO RELATE THESE TABLES DON'T HESITATE.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. Ternary associations are more of a theoretical construct in UML. They are seldom used in the "real" world, and definitely not when dealing with a database structure. Try not to complicate your life and use regular (binary) associations.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do ;)

Comment: In that case you'll have to explain your requirements in more detail. From the description you gave I'm not able to deduce a data model.

Comment: Do your 'users' sell/buy 'jobs'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two associations between your ternary and your User class, one association with the Job class and a dependency on the Feedback class: this is definitely not a ternary.

MCD and MLD are two abbreviations for [Merise diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merise) (largely used in France in the 90's, have a look at the [French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merise_%28informatique%29)), this is not UML compliant, here is why. These diagrams respectively represent a conceptual view and a logical (usually relational) view of the informations. Merise is not at all object-oriented, while UML is purely object-oriented.

The alternative I propose you is to forget your ternary. I don't understand how you can introduce a reflexive relationship between User and User. In my mind you have a real Feedback class which has a relationship on the buyer (of type User) and the seller (also of type User). In a way, as an object representation your UML diagram should be close to the Merise logical diagram (MLD) you did not produced but coded. It would be something like that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I agree with your solution but do you mean buyerS:user or just one buyer in class Feedback. because I think that the relation between class user and class Feedback is 0..* ------ 0..*.
Feedback has_many user and user has_many feedback.

Comment: Isn't it strange that in your proposal the `Job` class is not directly associated with `User`? So, if there is no feedback, how are `Job` and `User` related?

Comment: It depends on the context: the only information about the relationship between User and Job I had was that it was a ternary. As I understand things, a Feedback object holds more informations than a simple feedback. It materializes in fact a transaction between a buyer(s?) and a seller. What I could propose is to rename the Feedback class into Transaction. But you can have multiple feedbacks. One solution for that would be a Transaction class instead of the feedback and a Feedback class with one to many relationship with the transaction (I don't understand the point about multiple buyers).

Comment: Anyway, all I can do is suppositions: I don't know what is the domain, the context, the business. The solution I proposed was following SADOK's informations and it seemed to suit hit needs.